# Get the local IP address in sub Application_OnStart of global.asa?

Tags: asp-classic

While it seems that this has been asked many times before, but there's a nasty twist here...

First, I'm working on a desktop application which calls a webpage on the same local system. This web application then calls upon a second server (in the local network) and needs to pass it's own IP address to the other server. Easy, of course: `Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR")` and I'm done...

It won't work in this case... The code for the local web application is written in classic ASP and almost every sourcefile is encrypted, thus I cannot modify it's code. All I can fix is the global.asa file. In the Application_OnStart event of global.asa is the line `Application("InternalIp") = "172.22.14.59"` and indeed, that's the local IP address, hard-coded... And this application setting is used in the rest of the code to refer to the IP address.

However, my IP address in our local network tends to change every day, so every day I need to modify global.asa to contain my new IP address. I could write a small application which will modify global.asa for me every day on startup but I'd rather see a solution where global.asa would be smart enough to detect this IP address itself!
Unfortunately, the IP address must be known on the start of the application, not at the start of the session, else I could have used `Application("InternalIp") = Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR")` in the Session_OnStart event. Tried this, application crashed, so it won't work.
But that line of code in Application_OnStart won't work, since Request is unknown at that moment, thus that would crash too. (Tried it, didn't work...)

So, my limitation is that I need to get the IP address within the Application_OnStart event of global.asa in a reliable way. And no, using DNS names don't work either. (Tried that too, didn't work.) What options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the commandline (wscript.shell) and ipconfig?

or write your ip address in a textfile (with the help of another tool) and then read out that text file

you could also add an asp page to your application, call that asp page from your desktop application. on the new asp page you could everything you want (e.g. set the application var with the help of request.servervariables...) then at the end do a redirect to the "original" (encrypted) asp page...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Application_Onstart(), but in your Session_onStart() it should be possible to get the servervariables.
I work on a classic ASP application that does just that. I'm currently on a linux machine, so I can't run the code, only look at it over the network, but what we do is use an include in the Global.asa, just above the script tag:

```
<!--#include virtual="~inc/global.inc"-->
<script language=vbscript runat=server>
```

Then, in the SUB Session_OnStart we use a call to a function in that global.inc include that uses Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") to fetch the remote I.P. and log it in a database. If it works for the remote I.P. I think it should also work for the local I.P. Although I'm not sure if it will then log the localhost (127.0.0.1) or the external I.P....

Could you try with Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR"), just to see if that works If it doesn't; what is the error you get?

By the way: the way we work (using an include and a function call) should not matter; you should be able to do it directly from the session_Onstart

Comment: Application_Onstart can't access the server-variables through the session variable since there's no session yet. The biggest problem is that the code is relying on this IP address to be set before a session starts...

Comment: You can also try using microsofts serverxmlhttp object to do a GET to http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp 

This will give you yor external ip address. I don't know if you can instantate the serverxmlhttp object in application_onstart() however... 

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766431(v=vs.85).aspx for more info.

Comment: Only if access to the Internet is allowed. Unfortunately, it's an IntrAnet application and the outside world is most likely blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I posted this as a comment, but it is an alternative answer:

You can also try using microsofts serverxmlhttp object to do a GET to the API of whatsmyip.com: http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp

This will return your servers external ip address. I don't know if you can instantate the serverxmlhttp object in application_onstart() however...

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766431(v=vs.85).aspx for more info on how to use serverxmlhttp to do an HTTP GET.

Comment: Won't really work in an intranet environment, where the Evil Outside Internet is blocked by firewalls... :-( Nice idea, though...